# Installing QGIS 2.18 fails on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04)

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, qgis-2.18

I recently upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04. I had previously been using QGIS 2.14 which I had built from source against GDAL 2.10.

After the upgrade QGIS no longer worked so I attempted to install QGIS today and it fails at qgis-providers as follows:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what I may be missing? I've attempted to remove all traces of my old QGIS install/libraries/dependencies.

I'm installing against the debian sources:

```
deb     http://qgis.org/debian xenial main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian xenial main
```

Comment: That's more a linux problem than a gis problem... but please provide the output of ls /lib/ | grep libhdf5 (or from the appropriate lib folder). Maybe you just need to add a symlink: sudo ln -s libhdf5.so libhdf5.so.7 (once in the proper lib folder). Cheers

Comment: Thanks Victor - I found libhdf5 in  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so not sure where I should link it to though?

Comment: Try ln -s libhdf5.so libhdf5.so.7 in the folder where you've found the file. If not, maybe in the main /lib/ folder. I can't really give you more precise information right now, I'm using manjaro. I'll have a look tonight on ubuntu.

Comment: I did check on ubuntu last evening but my libhdf5 file is not in the same location (and I actually have a libhdf5-serial.so or something of the sort. AndreJ's solution is the proper way to fix your problem. Mine is just a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

The QGIS binaries from `http://qgis.org/debian xenial main` are compiled against GDAL 1.11.3, so you may run into trouble if you had GDAL 2.10 before.

I suggest to use the QGIS Ubuntugis repository `http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main` and the Ubuntugis unstable ppa, which already has GDAL 2.10 for Xenial. Make sure to remove QGIS **and** GDAL before installing.

Comment: thanks - I've tried this and QGIS installs but throws a bunch of pythin errors when on startup when it tries to load plugins. The package runs but the last error is: `Unable to load GdalTools plugin. 
The required "osgeo [python-gdal]" module is missing. 
Install it and try again.`

Comment: `python-gdal`2.1.0  is part of the ubuntugis gdal package. Pelase check if you have the same as https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=trusty . I remember to have to install python-qgis manually from the command line too.

Comment: weird, according to synaptic I have python gdal 2.1.0 installed. Is it not linked correctly or installed in a weird location that QGIS can't find? Seems to be in /usr/share/doc/

Comment: I have that folder too, but only containing some examples. Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application and installing GDAL, then QGIS from the command line. That way you see when packages are held back.